# Scroll WPF toolkit chart in touch screen

Tags: wpf, xaml, charts, scroll, wpftoolkit

I am using a WPF toolkit chart in my application which is for touch screen devices. I want to enable scrolling for the chart but don't want to show scroll bar to the user. How can I achieve this? Here is my code:-

```
<ScrollViewer>      
                <chartingToolkit:Chart Name="bottomChart"  BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" ClipToBounds="False"  >
                <chartingToolkit:Chart.PlotAreaStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="Grid">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    </Style>
                </chartingToolkit:Chart.PlotAreaStyle>
                <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
                    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="False" Visibility="Hidden" Width="0" Minimum="0"/>
                    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Interval="5"  ShowGridLines="True" Visibility="Hidden" Height="0" >
                    </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis>                       
                </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
                <chartingToolkit:Chart.TitleStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="Control">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    </Style>
                </chartingToolkit:Chart.TitleStyle>
                <chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="Control">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    </Style>
                </chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>

                <TestManagementUC:UnorderedLineSeries x:Name="BottomChartSeries" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataPoints}">
                    <TestManagementUC:UnorderedLineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Brush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        </Style>
                    </TestManagementUC:UnorderedLineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                </TestManagementUC:UnorderedLineSeries>                   

            </chartingToolkit:Chart>                
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: No one knows the answer :(